# Replace nested ifelse while working with dates in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is my data

```
sampleData <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J", "K"), Date = structure(c(1546300800, 1547510400, 
1547769600, 1548288000, 1548979200, 1549756800, 1550188800, 1551398400, 
1552348800, 1552608000, 1553472000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 11 x 2
Category Date               
<chr>    <dttm>             
1 A        2019-01-01 
2 B        2019-01-15 
3 C        2019-01-18 
4 D        2019-01-24 
5 E        2019-02-01 
6 F        2019-02-10 
7 G        2019-02-15 
8 H        2019-03-01 
9 I        2019-03-12 
10 J        2019-03-15 
11 K        2019-03-25 
lookupData <- structure(list(`Original Date` = structure(c(1546560000, 1547769600, 
1548979200, 1550188800, 1551398400, 1552608000, 1553817600, 1555027200, 
1556236800, 1557446400, 1558656000, 1559865600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 12 x 1
`Original Date`    
<dttm>             
 1 2019-01-04 
 2 2019-01-18 
 3 2019-02-01 
 4 2019-02-15 
 5 2019-03-01 
 6 2019-03-15 
 7 2019-03-29 
 8 2019-04-12 
 9 2019-04-26 
10 2019-05-10 
11 2019-05-24 
12 2019-06-07
```

Currently I have multiple ifelse() statements something like this to get this working.

```
sampleData$ModifiedDate <- ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-01-04", "2019-01-04",
                 ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-01-18", "2019-01-18",
                        ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-02-01", "2019-02-01",
                               ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-02-15", "2019-02-15",
                                      ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-03-01", "2019-03-01",
                                             ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-03-15", "2019-03-15",
                                                    ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-03-29", "2019-03-29",
                                                           ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-04-12", "2019-04-12",
                                                                  ifelse(sampleData$Date <= "2019-04-26", "2019-04-26","")))))))))
```

This works, but it is not the way I would want it. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I tried the `merge()` and `fuzzy_left_join()` options but I don't get the desired results like below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `cut`

Comment: I tried with `cut`. I used the lookup values as the `break` but got the error `'breaks' are not unique`.

Comment: FYI, your image of expected output is contains different category/date values as your `structure` sample above it.

Comment: @r2evans - yeah noticed it after I posted. I have updated it now. Thank you

Comment: krish, it appears that you accepted and then *un*-accepted an answer, suggesting that so far neither of the answers solves your problem. If the intention is (as manotheshark suggested) to use "every Friday", then `cut` really is a better option, and your `not unique` error can be remedied if you show what you did. If "every Friday" is not always true, then I think the non-equi join (aka range join) in `fuzzyjoin` is the way to go. Either way, if your issue is not resolved, then I think you need to [edit] your question with more details, namely why the two answers do not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt with `fuzzyjoin`:

```r
library(dplyr)

lookupData %>%
  mutate(z = lag(`Original Date`, default = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01"))) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
    sampleData, .,
    by = c(Date = "z", Date = "Original Date"),
    match_fun = list(`>`, `<=`)) %>%
  select(-z)
# # A tibble: 11 x 3
#    Category Date                `Original Date`    
#    <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>             
#  1 A        2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-04 00:00:00
#  2 B        2019-01-15 00:00:00 2019-01-18 00:00:00
#  3 C        2019-01-18 00:00:00 2019-01-18 00:00:00
#  4 D        2019-01-24 00:00:00 2019-02-01 00:00:00
#  5 E        2019-02-01 00:00:00 2019-02-01 00:00:00
#  6 F        2019-02-15 00:00:00 2019-02-15 00:00:00
#  7 G        2019-02-10 00:00:00 2019-02-15 00:00:00
#  8 H        2019-03-12 00:00:00 2019-03-15 00:00:00
#  9 I        2019-03-01 00:00:00 2019-03-01 00:00:00
# 10 J        2019-03-15 00:00:00 2019-03-15 00:00:00
# 11 K        2019-03-25 00:00:00 2019-03-29 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be better served with a formula as it appears you are advancing all dates to the following, 2nd Friday.  If that is correct then the following will accomplish that and does not matter how long the dates span.

Setting `baseDate` that is used to determine what is the first date for reference:

```
baseDate <- structure(1546560000, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
```

Using `ceiling` to advance the date to the following, 2nd Friday:

```
sampleData$NewDate <-  baseDate + ceiling((sampleData$Date - baseDate) / 14) * 14

   Category       Date    NewDate
1         A 2019-01-01 2019-01-04
2         B 2019-01-15 2019-01-18
3         C 2019-01-18 2019-01-18
4         D 2019-01-24 2019-02-01
5         E 2019-02-01 2019-02-01
6         F 2019-02-15 2019-02-15
7         G 2019-02-10 2019-02-15
8         H 2019-03-12 2019-03-15
9         I 2019-03-01 2019-03-01
10        J 2019-03-15 2019-03-15
11        K 2019-03-25 2019-03-29
```